# MySql - Predict user rank in leader board query

Tags: mysql, rank, leaderboard

I have a cooking leader board of my users, based on other users likes and another parameters of mine. Each user can have many dishes in the leader board.

This leader board is showing in real time. I am always querying it again to show my clients the most recent data.

Now I want to create an option to show my user just his dishes in the board, and I want to tell him what place they are.

How can I predict the rank of all my user dishes in the leader board?

Comment: can you count likes and display rank or is there any other crieteria for rank?

Comment: @raheelshan there is but it doesn't meter for the answer

Comment: Add your table structure and sample input data and output data